# memory allocation/pointer troubles or bad algorithm in C

Tags: c

I have writen a simple code in C. What I am trying to accomplish is given a string [similar to html] I am creating node pointer object. May be its called serialization or something but not sure.

For example, I have string `abccbccacca` in which `a` tag has two immediate children `ccacc` and `bccb` going further recursively deep  `bccb` tag `b` also has two children so two = c and each c are siblings together.

But this lines are in my thinking not doing what they suppose to.

```
        struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        struct node *t=n+i;
        t=temp;
        parse(arr,l,r,(struct node *)n+i);
```

What I am doing above is simply allocate n+i-th sibling and passing recursively.

I also tried like this

```
        (n+i)=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        parse(arr,l,r,(struct node *)n+i);
```

But the above does not compile and give error that lvalue should be ...

So I believe algorithm makes sense but I may need pointer to pointer for allocation if I want this to output something

```
struct node *no=n->ch;
struct node *no1=no->ch;
printf("\n%c\n",no1[2].c);
```

This is full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node {
    char c;
    struct node *ch;
};

int chcmp(char a,char b)
{
 if(a==b)
     return 1;
    
    return 0;
}

void parse(char *arr,int l,int r,struct node *n)
{
    if(arr[l]==arr[r])
    {
        n->c=arr[r];
        //printf(" &%c %c ",*(arr+r),*(arr+l));     
        n->ch=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r--;
        l++;
        printf("%c",n->c);
        
        parse(arr,l,r,n->ch);
    }
    //printf("\n");
    int i=0;

    while(r>l)
    {
        if(arr[r]!=arr[l])
        {
            //printf("[%c %c] %d\n",arr[r],arr[l],l);
            r--;
        }
        else    
        {
            struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            struct node *t=n+i;
            t=temp;
            parse(arr,l,r,(struct node *)n+i);
            l=r+1;
            
            r=strlen(arr);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *n=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    char *arr="abccbccacca";
     
    parse(arr,0,strlen(arr)-1,n);
    struct node *no=n->ch;
    struct node *no1=no->ch;
    printf("\n%c\n",no1[2].c);
}
```

Comment: What is `struct node *t=n+i;` supposed to do`? You immediately discard this value again by assigning `t=temp;` in the very next line. And also, you do not even use `t` anywhere. This causes all the memory you have allocated to be lost forever. Therefore... what do you expect to do here?

Comment: @Gerhardh I just want to allocate. ith index for n. Having this problem. so this is the question

Comment: But as I mentioned: You do not store or otherwise use that allocated memory. Please add some description to the question how your expected result should look like. It seems to be some mixture of tree and arrays. If `ch` points to more than one nodes, how would you know the number?

Comment: BTW: You also do not initialize your allocated nodes. They are containing random data after you receive the memory from `malloc`.

Comment: @Gerhardh n->c should contain `a` then if I do `struct node *p=n->ch;` then p[0]->c should contain `b` and p[1]->c should contain `c`

Comment: Please add this (more detailled) to the question. Best you show some larger hierarchy of your structures. What is result for `cbcbc`, `ccc`, `bcacab`? And as I already asked: How would anyone know if `p[1]` even exists if you do not store any number of children? Your whole structure is worthless if you are not able to access all the information afterwards.

Comment: In general I would say, that you have to put some restrictions on your input. If you do not limit that string to follow some specific rules, you will never be able to parse without significantly more effort. Also I think, your approach using `strlen` while parsing one element cannot work as it would reset `r` to the end of the initial string instead of narrowing your string down.

Comment: @Gerhardh Well I had to do this this allocation I needed. `*(n+i)=*(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` but found u are right on algorithm its not right

Comment: Well, this causes other problems. Besides the fact that you still don't know if you have 0, 1 or 195 entries stored in that array, you do not have any memory for more than 1 entry. You would need to increase the size.

Comment: Side note: your `chcmp` function can simply be written as `int chcmp(char a,char b) { return a == b; }`